# Import error: No module named jsonpickle

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jsonpickle

I get the following error:-

```
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXXXXXXXX/1-2-5-test.371816147108304389/finish.py", line 8, in <module>
    import jsonpickle
ImportError: No module named jsonpickle
```

I have jsonpickle (version 0.6.1) in the root directory. I use a couple of other 3rd party libraries in python without any problem in importing. Why is this only happening for jsonpickle? The weird thing is that this works well in local server and I'm getting the error only on the remote server.

I tried the solutions from [google app engine jsonpickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003817/google-app-engine-jsonpickle) question. None of them seem to work. Can anyone confirm my problem on GAE if possible?

Comment: Is jsonpickle in the same directory as finish.py, and are all the dependency's met (chosen backend) and in the same directory as finish.py so that everything is getting deployed ? and simplejson isn't in django in recent SDK's if your using that as the backend.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman jsonpickle needs no dependency on python 2.6+ (according to the traceback, it seems GAE has python27's libs) The folder jsonpickle is in the same directory as finish.py (just like I do with other plugins)

Comment: @TimHoffman Nope, I'm not using django's simplejson. I can understand [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/712799/679829) they have it removed since python 2.7 has json included in the std libs and jsonpickle would work with that.

Comment: reading the docs, there are dependancy's depending on the backend. However in this case it just can't find the module.  Do you have a complete install - is _____init_____.py  present in ./jsonpickle/

Comment: re:simplejson I was referring to the other answer you linked to in your original post

Comment: @TimHoffman Yes, `__init__.py` is present in ./jsonpickle/ folder just like the other plugins I have in folders. And thanks for letting me know about Django not having simplejson in GAE's recent SDKs.. maybe you should put a comment in those posts about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error installing the next

```
pip install jsonpickle
```